# Different data for sharing providers in UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to use an `UIActivityViewController` with one long `NSString` as the data. If I put a string > 140 characters, the tweet sheet in it does not display the string. And if I truncate the string before giving it to the controller, all of the `UIActivities` have the truncated string. I don't want Facebook or Message to be truncated.

Is there a way to give different strings to different `UIActivities`?

Thank you!

(e.g. Marco Arment's The Magazine app does this by having a truncated string followed by @TheMagazineApp in `UIActivityPostToTwitter`, and other stuff in other `UIActivities`.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: [Custom UIActivityViewController icons and text](https://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-and-text/).

You should be able to provide different data for each activity type.

Comment: if you want to customize existing providers (FB, Twitter, etc) --> -(id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType - is the function you want to edit - this is where you decide which items will get published

Comment: I don't get how you modify facebook/twitter etc text independently from this... do you have to initialize an APActivityProvider for each one that you want to be different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451583/uiactivityview-controller-behaviour-is-strange

Comment: I've Upgraded my project to SDK 9.x and received ( 'init' is unavailable ) error on APActivityProvider *ActivityProvider = [[APActivityProvider alloc] init] how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 11):

Hope this helps somebody. It's pretty straightforward if you subclass `UIActivityItemProvider`:

```
@interface MyActivityItemProvider : UIActivityItemProvider
@end

@implementation MyActivityItemProvider

- (id)item
{
    // Return nil, if you don't want this provider to apply 
    // to a particular activity type (say, if you provide 
    // print data as a separate item for UIActivityViewController).
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePrint]) 
        return nil;

    // The data you passed while initialising your provider 
    // is in placeholderItem now.
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] ||
        [self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard])
    {
        return self.placeholderItem;
    }

    // Return something else for other activities. Obviously, 
    // you can as well reuse the data in placeholderItem here.
    return @"Something else";
}

@end
```

Then pass its instance with an array of activity items to UIActivityViewController:

```
MyActivityItemProvider *activityItem = 
    [[MyActivityItemProvider alloc] initWithPlaceholderItem:@"Your data"];
NSArray *sharingItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    activityItem, _myUITextView.viewPrintFormatter, nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = 
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
        initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: This is exactly what is needed to share different kind of data. Just subclass as many UIActivityItemProviders as needed. One for each data type.

Comment: You shouldn't return nil since `item` is marked as nonnull.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done by using the optional `activityType` property from the [`UIActivityItemProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemprovider) object. That property returns a `UIActivityType`, so you can do something like:

```
class PhotoActivityItemProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {  
    ...

    override var item: Any {
        guard let activityType = self.activityType else {
            return photoURL.absoluteString
        }
        if activityType == .mail || activityType == .message {
            return "The photo link is \(photoURL.absoluteString)."
        }

        ...
    }
```

More information in my blog post: https://www.whitesmith.co/blog/control-what-youre-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that conforms to `UIActivityItemSource` and then pass its instance with an array of activity items to UIActivityViewController:, as @Mu-Sonic suggested.

If you want to know in which platform is the user sharing and return any specific data dependent on the tapped platform, override `public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any?`