# UIActivityViewController : Activity-Items configuration

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an `UIActivityViewController` with 3 different types of activity items.

`NSString`, `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` and `UIImage`.

When I twitter, facebook or send as mail the system always adds the string and the image but when I print the system uses the `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` unless I remove it from the `NSArray`. How can I tell the `UIActivityViewController` to use the `UIImage` for printing instead?

```
NSString *textToShare
= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %i",
   _car.make,_car.model, _car.constructionYear];

UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textDataToShare
= [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:textToShare];

UIImage* imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:_car.picture];

NSArray* items = @[textToShare,imageToShare,textDataToShare];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController
= [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
   initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will answer your question: [Different data for sharing providers in UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551042/different-data-for-sharing-providers-in-uiactivityviewcontroller)