# Figuring out which icon was clicked on in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

Using the "Social" Framework, when presenting the modal UIActivityViewController that displays all the usual social-media icons, is there a way to find out exactly which icon the user clicked on? Meaning, if they chose Twitter, Facebook, Mail, Message, etc?

I was expecting to possibly see some delegate methods for this class in the Docs but I don't see anything.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

The `UIActivityViewController` has the `completionHandler` property. Implement this handler to be notified.

```
UIActivityViewController *avc = ...;
avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    if (completed) {
        NSLog(@"The selected activity was %@", activityType);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah but that gets triggered AFTER the post is complete - which is too late for my purposes. What I'm doing is pre-populating the Tweet (or Facebook post, email msg., etc.) that the user is sending with some text. Except that piece of text will be different for Tweets, emails, etc. So I thought that as soon as the user clicks on the icon, I can then programmatically change the text. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You should have made your desire clear in your original question. You would have gotten much better results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551042/different-data-for-sharing-providers-in-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Thank you for the link - I'll check it out!

Comment: @sirab333 you should probably just have different buttons for each type - would make your life much easier.

Comment: @rmaddy  how can i add different text to facebook and twitter ?? any idea?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

The typealias `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler` in Swift 3 changed to

`public typealias UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler = (UIActivityType?, Bool, [Any]?, Error?) -> Swift.Void`

You can use the completionWithItemsHandler like this.

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    //Do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`completionHandler` is deprecated. Use `completionWithItemsHandler`.

```
activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    NSLog(@"completionWithItemsHandler, activityType: %@, completed: %d, returnedItems: %@, activityError: %@", activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581940/2177085

This also include to check is user shared through WhatsApp or Gmail. You can print activityType to add other types.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [finalMsg as NSString], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in

// Return if cancelled
if (!completed) {
    print("user clicked cancel")
    return
}

if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
    print("share throgh mail")
}
else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
    print("share trhought Message IOS")
}
else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
    print("posted to twitter")
}
else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
    print("posted to facebook")
}
else if activityType == UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard {
    print("copied to clipboard")
}
else if activityType! == "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" {
    print("activity type is whatsapp")
}
else if activityType! == "com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension" {
    print("activity type is Gmail")
}
else {
    // You can add this activity type after getting the value from console for other apps.
    print("activity type is: \(activityType)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet worked in my case:

```
[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
{

   NSLog(@"act type %@",act);
   NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;
   if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
     ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent";

   if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
     ServiceMsg = @"Post on twitter, ok!";

   if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ) 
     ServiceMsg = @"Post on facebook, ok!";

   if ( done )
   {
      UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ServiceMsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [Alert show];
      [Alert release];
   }
   else
   {
      // didn't succeed. 
   }
}];
```

Comment: This Method is Completion method. but i want to get when i click on Icon like FB or whatsapp than i wnat to get click event. so how can i do this ?