# Conditional Detection of Which Sharing Option Selection iOS Sharing Extension in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, share

I currently have an app in the store that I am updating. The app allows a user to click a button and then share the image using the iOS Sharing Extension.  Is there a way to detect which option the user has selected (ex: Facebook or Twitter) and then resize the image according to the option selected?  I know how to resize my image just have no clue where to begin with the conditional.

Currently this is what I have for my button:

```
if let image = sender.currentImage     {
        let objectsToShare = [image]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        //New Excluded Activities Code
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
        //

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: This has something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16681860/405525