# Send NSData via Airdrop

Tags: ios, airdrop

I've got a (for me) big problem.
I want to send a vcf-file with airdrop from my own app to another iOS device. I've got a NSData object, which i should convert to a vcf file, and this I should send with airdrop to another IOS device.
The NSData object works fine, i can send a vcc file with email, but with airdrop I left my limit.
I tried everything i found here in the forum and on developer.apple.com. But nothing works, I think the reason is, that i have no idea how too start the fix the problem.
Has anybody any idea how i can realize it?

THANKS

Comment: Are you ok with the receiver's device importing the incoming AirDrop directly in to the system Contacts/Phone app?

Comment: I#m sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Let me try to ask it differently; What do you want the experience to be on the device that relieves the AirDrop request?

Comment: I want to receive a vcf file, which will could be add to the address book of the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
NSString *contactName = nil; // name of person in vcard
NSData *vcfData = nil; // vcard data
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.vcf", contactName]]];
NSError *writeError;
if ([vcfData writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]) {
    NSArray *activityItems = @[fileURL];
    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    // failed, handle errors
}
```

If you still want to support providing NSData to some of the activities you will have to create some objects that conforms to [UIActivityItemSource](http://UIActivityItemSource) protocol and have some of them return nil where appropriate (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551408/share-data-with-different-types-in-uiactivityviewcontroller/26613380#26613380) for more details on that). You might find the [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html) project from Apple helpful too.