# Give thumbnail image with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share an image with text through `UIActivityViewController`. If I do this:

```
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, image], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Everything works fine. The problem is that I only want to share the image with certain activity types. i.e. when a user shares to Facebook I don't want to have an image, for everything else I do though. My problem is this stupid method is never called:

```
optional func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController,
       thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: String?,
                       suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage?
```

Which should be becuase it's defined in `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. Is there any work around to this?

---

So I believe to have made some headway here. Turns our if you pass multiple values of `self` when instantiating `UIActivityViewController` you can return multiple values in the `itemForActivityType` delegate method. So if I do this:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self, self], applicationActivities: nil)
```

I can return different values like this:

```
func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
    if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
        return ["hello", "world"]
    }
    else {
        return ["goodnight", "moon"]
    }
}
```

However, it seems that you can only return two values of the same type.

My new question is now, how would I return both an image and text?? The hunt continues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to share two different set of content you have to create two different itemsource

1. we can set different text content for different activity type.Add the **MyStringItemSource class**  to your viewcontroller

   **SourceOne:**

   ```
   class MyStringItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

   @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
       return ""
   }

   @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
       //You can pass different text for for diffrent activity type
       if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
           return "String for facebook"
       }else{
           return "String for Other"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Our requirement is to add image to all activity type **except FB**,to do that add the **MyImageItemSource class** in your VC.

   **SourceTwo:**

   ```
   class MyImageItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

   @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
      return ""
   }


   @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController:  UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
     //This one allows us to share image ecxept UIActivityTypePostToFacebook
     if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
        return nil
     }
     let Image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif")!)!)!
         return Image
     }   

   }
   ```
3. Now we are ready to set UIActivityViewController,here we go

   ```
   @IBAction func Test(sender: AnyObject) {

   let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyStringItemSource(),MyImageItemSource()] as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

   //Instead of using rootviewcontroller go with your own way.
   if let window = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window
   {
       window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   }
   ```

**TWITTER Shared Dialogue:**
Contains image and given text

[image]

**FB Share Dialogue:**
Contains only the given text

[image]