# Set thumbnail image for UIActivityViewController with smaller UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, thumbnails, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'd like to set a specific smaller thumbnail, but still use a high quality image for the activity item I'm sharing. My problem is when sharing large images, the thumbnail takes time to generate, which can cause problems when sharing it to certain apps.

For instance, if I present my UIActivity controller, and choose Messenger,

[image]

and I don't give time to let my thumbnail load, choose a person and hit send, it will never finish sending, and I need to cancel.

[image]

Only if I wait for the thumbnail to be generated, and then hit send, everything will then work.

[image]

In this case, "photo" is the high quality UIImage, but how do I set the thumbnail image to avoid it generating one out of the high quality image when the UIActivityViewController appears?

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [photo], applicationActivities: nil)

UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

There's a document about thumbnail images, but I'm not sure how implement it, or if it's helpful in this situation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource/1620462-activityviewcontroller

Also, I read up on UIActivityItemProvider, and it states:

> For example, you might use a provider object to represent a large video file that needs to be processed before it can be shared to a user’s social media account.

Does this mean it can hold off on displaying the app I want to share my image with until it's ready? I subclassed UIActivityItemProvider, and pass a thumbnail image, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm either doing something completely wrong, or this isn't what I want to use.

My subclassed UIActivityItemProvider:

```
class CustomProvider : UIActivityItemProvider {

    var image : UIImage!

    init(placeholderItem: AnyObject, image : UIImage) {
        super.init(placeholderItem: placeholderItem)
        self.image = image
    }

    override var item: Any {
        return self.image!
    }
}
```

I have a share function that is an extension. I create a thumbnail image and pass it to the placeholderItem in the CustomProvider function:

```
extension Equatable {
    func share() {

        let imageData = (self as! UIImage).pngData()!
        let options = [
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 300] as CFDictionary
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
        let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options)!
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: imageReference)


        let firstActivityItem = CustomProvider(placeholderItem: thumbnail, image: self as! UIImage)

        let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create a smaller `UIImage` image initially, while waiting for the other image to be created? Of course, if the user hits *send*, you will have to wait for the larger image to be created anyway. So, in any situation, you are still waiting for the image to be created. The question is - are you going to allow users to press "I want to send something" and show a smaller image initially, or wait till everything is ready to load? Either way, you are waiting for the image to be ready.

Comment: Yeah I don't mind having them wait. I just want something to appear there for the thumbnail, but ultimately send the larger image. But how do I do that?

Comment: Well, it depends; are you creating an image from within your app or obtaining it from the interwebs? If you are creating an image from within your app using an `AVAssetWriter` or something, then create 2 images. The first MUCH smaller (just a thumbnail size) and the other be the original. Use the smaller for your thumbnail and the original goes somewhere. If from the webs, then (if you are storing your own imagery) store 2 images, one of much smaller size.

Comment: My question, however, is that users have to wait to send the "original" image anywho, so why not just make them wait to send the image until the original is created?

Comment: The images are being made within my app, not the internet. The thumbnail seems to be created as the activity is selected, like Facebook Messenger, so I have no control over doing it beforehand. See code above. I can give it an array of activity items. If an image in that array signifies a thumbnail, I don't know which one it is. It seems to use whatever image is provided first in that array.

Comment: @impression7vx test and provide code in an answer that works according to the question, and I'll make it as correct.

Comment: Yes, but don't you have the original image `(self as! UIImage)` from the line `let imageData = (self as! UIImage).pngData()!`? Thus you have an image already. To be honest, not sure why you are creating another image from `self as! UIImage` if you already have the first image? That is a tad confusing.

Comment: The first image is the high quality image that takes too long to appear. That let imageData = (self as! UIImage).pngData()! is where a thumbnail size image is being created. Read through my entire question.

Answer (score 2):

Let the `ActivityViewController` do the work for you.

```
func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: String?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let maxSize = [size.width, size.height].max()
    let imageData = (self as! UIImage).pngData()!
    let options = [
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxSize as Any] as CFDictionary
    let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
    let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options)!
    let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: imageReference)
    return thumbnail
}
```

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [photo], applicationActivities: nil)

UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I didn't think you needed a specific `ActivityType` so this assumes all activities.

Also, make sure you extend `UIActivityItemSource`.

I used [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468195/give-thumbnail-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller) as a reference.

**Edit1**

Subclass `UIActivityItemSource`

```
class MyActivityType:NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    var image:UIImage!
    var placeholderImage:UIImage!

    convenience init(image:UIImage, placeholderImage:UIImage) {
        self.init()
        self.image = image
        self.placeholderImage = placeholderImage
    }

    //Placeholder - we use `return UIImage()` so the sheet knows it is an image
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return self.placeholderImage
    }

    //Actual item you are sending
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return self.image
    }

    //Thumbnail - Apple states that `For activities that support a preview image, returns a thumbnail preview image for the item.` but since you are pushing an image for your item, should be good to go.
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return self.placeholderImage
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors on this - but I can't run it, so I don't see any runtime errors.

You can then send as such --

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in

    let imageData = (self! as! UIImage).pngData()!
    let options = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 300] as CFDictionary
    let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
    let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options)!
    let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: imageReference)

    //Back to main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

        //Remove loading indicator
        let firstActivityItem = MyActivityType(image: (self! as! UIImage), placeholderImage: thumbnail)

        let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could generate a low quality image in your application and reference that url in the UIActivityViewController

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(
activityItems: ["Some description", url],
applicationActivities: nil)
```

You may use the following to generate a low quality image which can be locally saved later:

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

... or refer the following post for more technical knowledge and ways to do it:
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Credits. Material extracted from the following locations:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation
- https://thomasguenzel.com/blog/2015/04/16/uiactivityviewcontroller-nsdata-with-filename/

Comment: Won't that never send the high quality image? That appears to just send a low quality image.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood the requirement "Messenger degrading quality or size of the sent image beyond your control is OK." as you are fine with degraded quality.

Comment: But it seems trivial with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource/1620462-activityviewcontroller (the link you shared). Simply subclass UIActivityViewController and set it as UIActivityItemSource (same as you do UITableViewControllers datasource). Then in the implementation of the above method, return a scaled down version

Comment: Degraded quality after sending a large, high quality photo to Messenger cannot be avoided. That happens on their end. It's when you send a large photo and don't wait for the square thumbnail of the photo to appear in the modal view is when problems occur. I confirmed this is a problem with some apps including Messenger and in contact with the Facebook Team about it now.